# How to write a unit test to ensure output is within certain limits?

Tags: unit-testing, random

If I have a requirement that says the output of a function must always be within certain limits, how can I test this if the function returns unpredictable results?

For example, lets say I have a function that generates random numbers or passwords; how can I test that the number is always between 1000 and 9999 or the password is always between 6-12 characters?

Let's use the number generator example - currently I would write two tests: one that runs the function in a finite loop and tests each result is >= 1000 and a second that ensures the output is <= 9999. Obviously the loop must be run a large number of times (>9K) for each test to have any chance of covering all the possible output values.

**Are there any better approaches (i.e. ones that would be considered more reliable) when testing the output of unpredictable functions**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you want to test every possible input, and make sure that the output is what you expect.

If you are testing a function with a random aspect, then this is difficult to do because it will have different outputs for the same input.

If possible, I would find where exactly the random value is used and then test every possible value that might come from that random value generator, but if you are testing the random value generator itself then your method you have described seems to be the best option.

Comment: Forgot to mark this as the answer - since I'm not testing the generator itself, I've replaced the generator with a fake one and tested at the limits, and in some situations by cycling through the values.